# Energy momentum tensor of a perfect fluid with vanishing density?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I came across a stress tensor in general relativity that has the form:

$$T_{\mu\nu} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & w & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & { - w} & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{array}} \right]$$

in other words, there are two components of pressure and zero energy density. Is such a thing possible? What would it physically mean?

Comment: I suspect this has faster-than-light flow, ie violates the flux energy condition.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the metric it may violate all or most of the positive energy conditions that have been proposed to insure the universe does not have negative mass. In all (or most) one of the conditions if $\rho$ $>=$ $|p|_i$ for each of the  three pressures.

Depending on the metric, it could (it does in Minkowski spacetime) violate the strong energy condition, the weak energy condition and the dominant energy condition, used as assumptions in many GR theorems and results as non-physical.

See the article at

http://strangebeautiful.com/papers/curiel-primer-energy-conds.pdf

For the many energy conditions that are used, and violations shown in various solutions found that in most cases are deemed as non-physical. You might find some answer there

I do not know specifically what physics your stress energy tensor might represents but with no energy density and opposite pressures in two coordinate directions it may represent orthogonal excitations. It really depends also on the metric, you'd have to define a solution. I think clearly not Minkowski. Not immediately obvious what but I think you have some idea. If not Minkowski and a perturbation with the p's small, see what you get.

Comment: Thank you Bob Bee. Do you have a reference on the "orthogonal excitations" you mention?

Comment: No, I am guessing from your two axis pressures. It might not be excitations, but an expansion in one axis and contraction in the other. you have a perfect fluid with zero density and oppositely directed pressures in two coordinate direction, I have not seen that before.

Comment: The derivation of the null energy condition has only been achieved in recent years by establishing an equivalence to the strong subadditivity of entanglement entropy, and this only applies in AdS spaces. There is no yet a similar claim for de-Sitter spaces, which are believed to be metastable